# Making main accept object other than string?

Tags: java

Is it possible to have the main method accept an argument other than a *string* array? For example, can we have a method like `main(Animals[]args){/*code*/}`? If not, then why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the entry point is always the method with the header `public static void main(String[] args)` (i.e. the JVM invokes this particular method). You can certainly define a method

```
public static void main(Animals[] args) {...}
```

but it would not be executed directly upon running the program.

---

***EDIT***: The reason the `main` method specifically has a string-array argument is because this array will contain the [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) when the program is run. Intuitively, these should be strings (and certainly not `Animal`s, for example).

Comment: Why does Java main have to have strings ? Why not any other type of object ?

Answer (score 2):

Because when you input from the command line you are entering strings, not a complex type.

So it makes sense for the argument to be an array of pointers (references) to strings, including or not (depending on the language) the count of the arguments. In Java this isn't needed as you can just use `length`.

Not sure why you'd want that?..

Comment: It was just a random thought.

Answer (score 1):

The [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1-100) says it can only handle array of Strings.

Comment: but i wanted to know why they do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from having a public static void main that takes a parameter type other than String. The problem is the that the JVM needs simple rules for identifying and calling the method. It has an array of strings, e.g. from the command line, available to pass to the program. How would the JVM go about turning it into an array of Animal, or some other type, before it has started running your program?

Here's an example of a main that takes a different parameter type, and of the program itself dealing with producing the Animal array from the array of strings that the JVM has. Of course, it would really be better to give the second main method a more meaningful name.

```
  import java.util.Arrays;

  public class Bad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Animal[] animals = new Animal[args.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        animals[i] = new Animal(args[i]);
      }
      main(animals);
    }

    public static void main(Animal[] args) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args));
    }

  }

  class Animal {
    String species;

    public Animal(String species) {
      this.species = species;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Animal: " + species;
    }
  }
```