# Evaluating JSON Payload dynamically using Java code

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement. I will get a JSON Payload and an expression as inputs and I need to dynamically evaluate the expression using the JSON payload and return the output

For instance, I have **JSON Payload** as :{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}
and
**Expression** as : payload.getString("firstname") + ' ' + payload.getString("lastname")

and I need to return output as : John Doe

when I use following code, it is working fine and returning expected output i.e. John Doe.
However, when I am passing the expression as args[0] it is not working as expected and returning my expression as output

**EvalTwo.java**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class EvalTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Function<JSONObject, Object> expression = payload -> 
                payload.getString("firstname") + ' ' + payload.getString("lastname");

        Evaluator evaluator = new Expression(expression);

        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject("{\"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Doe\"}");
        Object result = evaluator.eval(payload);

        if (result instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Output: " + result.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Expression.java**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Expression implements Evaluator {
    private final Function<JSONObject, Object> expression;

    public Expression(Function<JSONObject, Object> expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    @Override
    public Object eval(JSONObject payload) throws JSONException, ParseException {
        try {
            return expression.apply(payload);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error evaluating expression", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Evaluator.java**

```
import java.text.ParseException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public interface Evaluator {
    Object eval(JSONObject payload) throws JSONException, ParseException;
}
```

**Passing args[0] as input**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class EvalTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Function<JSONObject, Object> expression = payload -> args[0];
                

        Evaluator evaluator = new Expression(expression);

        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject("{\"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Doe\"}");
        Object result = evaluator.eval(payload);

        if (result instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Output: " + result.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like it is taking my args[0] as string not as an expression. Is there way, I can pass Payload and expression as arguments like args[0] and args[1] and get the required output.

Note: I have a flexibility to change the expression that is coming as input in case required.

FYI: I am new to Java field.

Thanks for your support !!!

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Please show how you invoke the program... i.e. what does the complete command line look like, and how is it being invoked (shell, another program, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

You defined above args as a String array. args[0] is the first element of that array. Java main can only accept String array as argument.

Please refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261251/making-main-accept-object-other-than-string) for more details.